# ES5 effectively equivalent to ES6 my lambda search?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I made es6 search on array and can't get figure out hot to rewrite this to es5 because of cordova that don't allow me to use lambda...

```
$scope.Contact.title = $scope.doctitles[$scope.doctitles.findIndex(x => x.id == $localStorage.data.contacts[$localStorage.data.itemID].title.id)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$scope.Contact.title = $scope.doctitles[$scope.doctitles.findIndex(function(x) {
    return x.id == $localStorage.data.contacts[$localStorage.data.itemID].title.id;
})];
```

You simply replace the lambda with a function.

EDIT: Since findIndex is also ES6, you can use this polyfill:

```
if (!Array.prototype.findIndex) {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function(predicate) {
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.findIndex called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is also part of ES6

Comment: @ralh: Did you write the polyfill yourself? If not, please cite (link) where you've copied it from.